# How to use a driver for Ubuntu with a higher kernel version(2.6.36) on ubuntu with lower kernel version (2.6.30))

Tags: drivers, kernel, downgrade

I want to use ***EASYCAP*** on my Ubuntu(**kernel version 2.6.30**).
The problem is that ,the drivers for ***EASYCAP*** are included in **kernel version 2.6.36** and higher.
I have extracted all the files corresponding to **EASYCAP DRIVER** from **linux-2.6.36/drivers/staging/easycap**.

And now i am stuck as while trying to make it it simply says
  ***make:No targets. Stop***

I could have understood if it showed that its not getting Header Files.

Any one having any idea how to do this,or how could i use ***EASYCAP***.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty old kernel... Which release of Ubuntu are you running? Can you possibly upgrade to a newer version? It would help you reach your goal...

[Many easycap bugs have been fixed in the newer kernels.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/892524/comments/2)

Barring that, you may be able to find a newer kernel if you enable the backports and/or testing repositories if you haven't already done so.

Finally, you could [compile your own mainline kernel.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds?action=show&redirect=KernelMainlineBuilds)